# how to get the integer array to pass to controller using data in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

This is the jquery ajax to add data from one selectlist to another.
I'm getting first Id if i use parseInt but i want an array
and the selectlist should be refreshed as i add(on click of #selImpactArea) even this isn't working

```js
//dialog popup
$("#CcUninitDept").dialog({
  title: "Add Departments",
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  dialogClass: 'custom-dialog',
  buttons: {
    Add: function() {
      var Departments = new Array();
      $.each($("#selUninitDeptDialog option:selected"), function() {
        Departments.push($(this).val());
      });
      if (Departments.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "/ChangeControl/AddInitiatedDepartments",
          data: {
            CcId: CcId,
            Departments: parseInt(Departments)
          },
          processing: false,
          asynch: true,
          cache: false,
          dataType: "Json",
          success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
              $('#selImpactArea')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                  .val(value.Department_Id)
                  .html(value.Department_Name));
              //$('#selImpactArea').find('option').reload();
            });
          },
          error: function(response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
          }
        });
      }
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I have difficulty understanding your question. You talk about parseInt, selectboxes and arrays but I don't know what your specific problem is. Besides your code snippet contains errors and therefore won't run. Could you clarify your question by isolating the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: in this region in departments i want to pass an array                                                         
   data: {
            CcId: CcId,
            Departments: parseInt(Departments)
          }    and it's working for only one id, but i want to pass multiple id's

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by 'Region'. If it's a HTML portion, please include it in your question.

Comment: in this region **departments** in data attribute of ajax- i want to pass an array                                                         
   `data: {
            CcId: CcId,
            Departments: parseInt(Departments)
          }`  i'm adding values from (#selUninitDeptDialog->its a selectlist or dropdown) to another dropdown or selectlist (#selImpactArea)

Answer (score 0):

well, parseInt parses a value and returns an integer. So if I'm correct, you want this:

```
data: {
    CcId: CcId,
    Departments: parseInt(Departments)
},
```

to be:

```
data: {
    CcId: CcId,
    Departments: Departments.map(val => parseInt(val, 10)),
},
```

This only works if `Departments` is an array.

Comment: `var Departments = new Array();
      $.each($("#selUninitDeptDialog option:selected"), function() {
        Departments.push($(this).val());
      });` i have `Departments` as array only..but it doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? Please specify exactly, which operation on which line 'does not work'.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adding traditional attribute `data: { CcId: CcId, Departments: Departments}, traditional:true,`